# how to multiply a Jspinner and a double variable?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that simulates a checkout of items. And I would like the amount of items to multiply with the unit cost to get the total cost but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to do this.

Here's my code.

```
    JLabel amount0 = new JLabel("Amount");
    JLabel unitcost0 =new JLabel("Unit Cost");
    JLabel unitcost1 = new JLabel("$2.45");
    JLabel unitcost2 = new JLabel("$79.99");
    JLabel unitcost3 = new JLabel("$45.43");
    JLabel unitcost4 = new JLabel("$3.00");
    JLabel unitcost5 = new JLabel("$42.00");
    JSpinner amount1= new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1));
    JSpinner amount2= new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1)); 
    JSpinner amount3 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1));
    JSpinner amount4= new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1));
    JSpinner amount5 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1));
    
    
    JLabel cost0 = new JLabel("Cost");
    JLabel cost1 = new JLabel ( unitcost1* amount1);
```

any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can only perform math operations with numbers, so in your case you need to store the numbers as a number variable like a `Double`:

```
Double price = 2.45;
```

Then you can use that number variable in your components:

```
JLabel yourLabel = new JLabel("$" + price);
```

Then to calculate the cost you need to get the number value of the jSpinner:

```
int spinnerValue = yourSpinner.getValue();
```

And to calculate the final totals:

```
Double total = price * spinnerValue;
JLabel cost1 = new JLabel ("$" + total);
```

Note that if you want this to happen live as you change the jSpinner then you need to create an action event on the jSpinners that will update the values/labels, this is a much bigger topic and requires a new question, but here is a rough example:

```
spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        int spinnerValue = ((JSpinner)e.getSource()).getValue();
        Double total = price * spinnerValue;
        yourLabel.setText("$" + total);
    }
});
```